# is play 2.5.2 ok to develop a websocket application

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am new to play framework. I am going to develop a web application in it using java.
In that web application i want to use websocket. websocket is the main part of my application.

By using a web socket i want to send json data to client and client will display a table of that information.

currently I am studying a bout play framework. i install 2.5.2 play.

My quesion is that, is play 2.5.2 ok to develop a websocket application?
because i am not getting sufficient information about it on internet.
so what should i do? where i can get it? it is ok with 2.5.2 version?

On www.playframework.com website I am not getting sufficent information about websocket and how to use it. sample exmple i am not getting. what should i do in this case? please help me.

Comment: Maybe discuss a specific use case or goal you had in mind.  Play's website is a good starting point: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets

Comment: i am not getting a sample example of it. all method of websocket in this vesrion are deprecated.

Comment: Maybe in the templates you can find something: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates. Although most templates are probably not for Play 2.5 but older versions. If I remember right they changed the WebSocket usage with 2.5 quite a bit.

Comment: Do you want to use actors or callbacks to handle the websocket connections?

Comment: yes I want just sample example that how to use it. I think there are two ways to do it. if i get both ways then it will very good.